# How to persist a JS object in database/anywhere else?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, cron

I am using [this cron npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) for creating cron job in my node server.

Here's my code:

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
//every minute cron job
var cron = new cronJob("* * * * *", function() {
     console.log("lorem ipsum");
}, null, true);
```

Now I need to store variable cron as it is somewhere where I can point to whenever I need. It is a JS object:

```
CronJob {
    context: [Circular],
        _callbacks: [ [Function] ],
        onComplete: null,
        cronTime:
    { source: '* * * * *',
        second: { '0': true },
        minute:
        { '0': true,
            '1': true,
            '2': true,
            '3': true,
            '4': true,
            '5': true,
            '6': true,
            '7': true,
            '8': true,
            '9': true,
            '10': true,
            '11': true,
            '12': true,
            '13': true,
            '14': true,
            '15': true,
            '16': true,
            '17': true,
            '18': true,
            '19': true,
            '20': true,
            '21': true,
            '22': true,
            '23': true,
            '24': true,
            '25': true,
            '26': true,
            '27': true,
            '28': true,
            '29': true,
            '30': true,
            '31': true,
            '32': true,
            '33': true,
            '34': true,
            '35': true,
            '36': true,
            '37': true,
            '38': true,
            '39': true,
            '40': true,
            '41': true,
            '42': true,
            '43': true,
            '44': true,
            '45': true,
            '46': true,
            '47': true,
            '48': true,
            '49': true,
            '50': true,
            '51': true,
            '52': true,
            '53': true,
            '54': true,
            '55': true,
            '56': true,
            '57': true,
            '58': true,
            '59': true },
        hour:
        { '0': true,
            '1': true,
            '2': true,
            '3': true,
            '4': true,
            '5': true,
            '6': true,
            '7': true,
            '8': true,
            '9': true,
            '10': true,
            '11': true,
            '12': true,
            '13': true,
            '14': true,
            '15': true,
            '16': true,
            '17': true,
            '18': true,
            '19': true,
            '20': true,
            '21': true,
            '22': true,
            '23': true },
        dayOfMonth:
        { '1': true,
            '2': true,
            '3': true,
            '4': true,
            '5': true,
            '6': true,
            '7': true,
            '8': true,
            '9': true,
            '10': true,
            '11': true,
            '12': true,
            '13': true,
            '14': true,
            '15': true,
            '16': true,
            '17': true,
            '18': true,
            '19': true,
            '20': true,
            '21': true,
            '22': true,
            '23': true,
            '24': true,
            '25': true,
            '26': true,
            '27': true,
            '28': true,
            '29': true,
            '30': true,
            '31': true },
        month:
        { '0': true,
            '1': true,
            '2': true,
            '3': true,
            '4': true,
            '5': true,
            '6': true,
            '7': true,
            '8': true,
            '9': true,
            '10': true,
            '11': true },
        dayOfWeek:
        { '0': true,
            '1': true,
            '2': true,
            '3': true,
            '4': true,
            '5': true,
            '6': true } },
    running: true,
        _timeout:
    Timeout {
        _called: false,
            _idleTimeout: 15995,
            _idlePrev:
        TimersList {
            _idleNext: [Circular],
                _idlePrev: [Circular],
                _timer: [Object],
                _unrefed: false,
                msecs: 15995 },
        _idleNext:
            TimersList {
            _idleNext: [Circular],
                _idlePrev: [Circular],
                _timer: [Object],
                _unrefed: false,
                msecs: 15995 },
        _idleStart: 162,
            _onTimeout: [Function: callbackWrapper],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
            _repeat: null } }
```

I need to store this kind of object somewhere. There are lets say 500 jobs running on server, I will need to store 500 references of cron. I want to store because I want to call cron.stop() function if I ever want to stop the cron job.

What I did was created a js object:

```
this.jobs = {};
```

And everytime job is created,

I add a key as job_id and value as cron in js object:

```
this.jobs[job.job_id] = cron;
```

But this doesn't seem to work everytime. I don't always get the value when I do:

```
this.jobs[job.job_id]
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is there any other way to persist the cron object? or I can the current way so that it works?

I tried to convert the object into JSON [using cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and using JSON.decycle and JSON.retrocycle functions. But they don't convert exact JS object to JSON.

Here's the main code:

```
var cronTab = function() {
  this.jobs = {};
};


cronTab.prototype.add = function(job) {
  if (this.jobs[job.id]) return false;
  var cron = new cronJob(job.expression, function() {
      console.log("lorem ipsum");  
  }, false, true);

  this.jobs[job.id] = cron;
  return true;
}

cronTab.prototype.remove = function(job) {
// When i try to access here in remove function, its not working at times
  if (!this.jobs[job.id]) return false;
  this.jobs[job.id].stop(); 
  delete this.jobs[job.id];
  return true;
}

cronTab.prototype.update = function(job) {
  return this.remove(job) && this.add(job);
}
```

Comment: Can you show a simple reproducible example of how you use `this.jobs` and it doesn't work?

Comment: If you really need to convert your object to JSON, you can use `JSON.stringify(objectName)`

Comment: JSON.stringify doesn't work when we have circular references in the object. See the cron output

Comment: I would not use this approach at all, especially if you have that many jobs. Instead, consider either using your OS's native scheduler or else setting up a job queue